# List of ancestry ability bonuses

Tags: ability-scores, pathfinder-2e, races

What are the ability bonuses for each ancestry?

This might be very useful in picking the right ancestry for a build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Up to date as of 09/10/2022 - these are all first-party ancestries from the SRD. At this time, the latest released ancestry is the Skeleton from the Book of the Dead, which was released in April of 2022.

### Common Ancestries:

| Ancestry | Boosts | Flaw |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dwarf | Con, Wis, Free | Cha |
| Elf | Dex, Int, Free | Con |
| Gnome | Con, Cha, Free | Str |
| Goblin | Dex, Cha, Free | Wis |
| Halfling | Dex, Wis, Free | Str |
| Human | Free, Free | None |

### Uncommon Ancestries:

| Ancestry | Boosts | Flaw |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Azarketi | Con, Cha, Free | Wis |
| Catfolk | Dex, Cha, Free | Wis |
| Fetchling | Dex, Free | None |
| Gnoll | Str, Int, Free | Wis |
| Grippli | Dex, Wis, Free | Str |
| Hobgoblin | Con, Int, Free | Wis |
| Kitsune | Cha, Free | None |
| Kobold | Dex, Cha, Free | Con |
| Leshy | Con, Wis, Free | Int |
| Lizardfolk | Str, Wis, Free | Int |
| Orc | Str, Free | None |
| Ratfolk | Dex, Int, Free | Str |
| Tengu | Dex, Free | None |

### Rare Ancestries:

| Ancestry | Boosts | Flaw |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anadi | Dex, Wis, Free | Con |
| Android | Dex, Int, Free | Cha |
| Automaton | Str, Free | None |
| Conrasu | Con, Wis, Free | Cha |
| Fleshwarp | Con, Free | None |
| Goloma | Wis, Free | None |
| Poppet | Con, Cha, Free | Dex |
| Shisk | Int, Free | None |
| Shoony | Dex, Cha, Free | Con |
| Skeleton | Dex, Cha, Free | Int |
| Sprite | Dex, Int, Free | Str |
| Strix | Dex, Free | None |

This link should be an evergreen list of relevant ancestry details, although it lacks the rarity and is not the official SRD, so we can't guarantee it's up to date. (Although historically pf2easy has been *very* good about being up to date and accurate): https://pf2easy.com/index.php?id=2496&name=ancestries

Characters of any ancestry can instead choose Alternative Ability Boosts as of the [4th CRB printing](https://paizo.com/pathfinder/faq), replacing any of the above specific modifiers with the default human's two free boosts.

Comment: You might want to add https://pf2easy.com/index.php?id=2496&name=ancestries

Comment: @SpearCarrier.no2 I had to add the Skeleton anyway, so I added the link. In the future, don't hesitate to add it yourself - it's a community wiki for that very reason :).